# Finding $\lim _{x\to2}\frac{x^{15}-2^{15}}{x-2}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Please I would it if anyone can breakdown the process of solving

$$\lim _{x\to2}\frac{x^{15}-2^{15}}{x-2}$$

I've tried solving but couldn't get it. Used an online solver and it came up with $245760$, but I would really love to know the process of solving it.

Comment: x-2 is a factor of the numerator, so you should be able to factorise and cancel the denominator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple: just use L'Hopital Rule...

$$\lim_{x \to 2}\frac{x^{15}-2^{15}}{x-2}$$
which gives $$\lim_{x \to 2}15x^{14}=15(2)^{14}=245760$$

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: To apply LH in this case is absurd.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**. One may prove that, for $x,a, \in \mathbb{R}$ and for $n=1,2,\cdots$, 
$$
x^n-a^n=(x-a)(x^{n-1}+a\cdot x^{n-2}+\cdots+a^{n-2}\cdot x+a^{n-1}).
$$ Can you apply it?

Answer (score 3):

Without calculus, [Olivier Oloa](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2190921/159845)'s answer gives you the way to go by factoring (binomial formula).

If you are allowed to use calculus, this is a limit where l'Hôpital's rule is very efficient:
$$\lim_{x \to 2} \frac{x^{15}-2^{15}}{x-2}= \lim_{x \to 2} \frac{\left(x^{15}-2^{15}\right)'}{\left( x-2 \right)'} = \lim_{x \to 2} \left( 15x^{14} \right) = 15\cdot 2^{14} = 245\,760 $$
If you haven't heard of this rule but you know derivatives, write $\color{blue}{f(x)=x^{15}}$ and compare with:
$$f'(a) = \lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} \quad\leftrightarrow\quad \color{blue}{\lim_{x \to 2} \frac{x^{15}-2^{15}}{x-2}=f'(2)}$$
to notice that your limit is precisely the *definition* of the derivative of $f(x)=x^{15}$ at $x=2$ to arrive at $f'(2)=15\cdot 2^{14}= 245\,760$ again.

Comment: thanks..heard of l'hopital's rule but had no idea what it was used for

Comment: To apply LH in this case is absurd.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the $x$ up top by $x-2 + 2$:

$$((x-2)+2)^{15} - 2^{15}$$

When this is expanded, you get, for some complicated bunch of coefficients $a_k$:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n a_k (x-2)^k + 2^{15} - 2^{15}=\sum_{k=1}^n a_k (x-2)^k$$

When you divide this by $x-2$ and set $x=2$, the only thing left is $a_1$. What is $a_1$? Well, applying the binomial formula, it's $\binom{15}{1}2^{14}=245760$.